# Monopoly : Is buying properties second time round a house rule or official rule?

Tags: house-rules, monopoly

Just wondering that when playing a normal game of monopoly, can I buy a property when I haven't passed go yet. Anything will help. thanks!

Comment: What rule are you referring to with "buying properties second time round"?

Comment: @BenjaminCosman I think what the OP means to ask is that in some "rule modalities" you can't buy properties during the first round of the game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I gather from your question the rule you are talking about is a house rule. In the basic rules it is intended for all properties to be sold the first time anyone lands on them. Either from the person that landed on it making the purchase or it being sold in auction.

In general the basic rules tend to make the game faster.

Comment: I would love it if someone could track down the origins of all these "house rules" to monopoly. The actual rules are pretty short and direct, yet I remember playing with all sorts of odd rules as a kid as well. Did we just not bother to read the directions? Not understand them? Invent rules for the fun (or lack thereof) it? Or were they passed down, parent to friend to sibling to cousin, through the ages, slowly corrupting Monopoly from a decent game into an almost intolerable one?